# Why does this regex for iso8601 fail for UTC times specified with the Z suffix?

Tags: c#, regex

Here's the regex:

```
^(-?(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9]{4})-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(3[0-1]|0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9])T(2[0-3]|[0-1][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(\\.[0-9]+)?(Z|[+-](?:2[0-3]|[0-1][0-9]):[0-5][0-9])?$
```

The problem is this regex is not matching strings with the Z suffix. Strings with the UTC offset specified as +0 or -0 work fine but Z does not. What's wrong with the regex and how do I correct it?

```
"2012-06-21T19:32:26.2311892-04:00"  // is a match
"2012-06-21T19:32:26.2311892-00:00"  // is a match
"2012-06-21T19:32:26.2311892+00:00"  // is a match

"2012-06-21T19:32:26.2311892Z" // not a match
```

Comment: (Z|[+-] should be ([Z+-]

Comment: @SaddamAbuGhaida No, it shouldn't.

Comment: The strings that you say match don't actually match, because you have `\\.` instead of `\.`. Is that because you copied it from a C# non-verbatim string literal? Other than that, the version with `Z` does match for me.

Comment: The decimal part of your strings are not matched.  Try a regex tester such as http://regexhero.net/ where you can see in real time how much of your data is being matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `\\.` in the expression where it should be just `\.`. With that corrected, your example input with a `Z` suffix successfully matches.

Comment: I put that as a comment on the question, instead of an answer, because if the OP is using a C# non-verbatim string literal (the question is tagged C#), the double backslash is correct.

Comment: Indeed. One can reasonably assume that it may inadvertently be showing an escaped string, however. :)

Comment: I replaced the \\ with \ and it now works fine. The problem was my approach to testing the regex. I need the double backslash in code as the regex is placed in a json schema. RegexPlanet.com, however, doesn't need the double backslash. Sanity restored...

Answer (score 0):

What's the version of .NET?
If I test in Visual Studio 2012 (.NET 4.5, 4.0, 2.0), everything works fine.

```
Regex rx = new Regex("^(-?(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9]{4})-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(3[0-1]|0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9])T(2[0-3]|[0-1][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(\\.[0-9]+)?(Z|[+-](?:2[0-3]|[0-1][0-9]):[0-5][0-9])?$");
string[] times = new[] {
    "2012-06-21T19:32:26.2311892-04:00",
    "2012-06-21T19:32:26.2311892-00:00",
    "2012-06-21T19:32:26.2311892+00:00",
    "2012-06-21T19:32:26.2311892Z" };
foreach (string time in times)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", time, rx.IsMatch(time));
```

Output:

```
2012-06-21T19:32:26.2311892-04:00 - True
2012-06-21T19:32:26.2311892-00:00 - True
2012-06-21T19:32:26.2311892+00:00 - True
2012-06-21T19:32:26.2311892Z - True
```

Comment: .NET 4.5, vs2013. The problem was the regex being stored as a string in JSON for a JSON schema project.

Answer (score 0):

you can check this regex i just checked it and it works fine

```
\d{4}-[0-1]\d-[0-3]\dT[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-6]\d{1,}.\d{1,}([+|-]\d{2}:\d{2}|Z)
```

Comment: According to [json-schema-validation §3.3](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor6), `\d` should be avoided in regular expressions intended for use in a JSON Schema.

Comment: @280Z28 true, but the question was to parse normal regex he didnt mention anything about JSON Parsing. because Date could be tokenized in json string and then convert it to date object

Comment: I didn't down vote you, just informative now that more information was given by the OP. :)

Comment: ya i Know. but i just added it for the sake of sharing the information :)